# TriggerShortcut "STRG + Plus-button" with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

To improve the user-experience for older Users, who do not know all the functions and shortcuts of their browser, I would like to have a button which simply triggers <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> (plus-button) to zoom in and improve the readability.

1. Is this possible?
2. How?
3. Is there a solution for Mac-users who do have an other button for <kbd>Strg</kbd>?

---

**Edit:** Seems like I could use the zoom property in CSS3.

I just tried:

```
function mzi(){

var oldval = document.getElementById('zoom').style.zoom;
var newval = Number(oldval) + 0.1;

alert('old value is '+Number(oldval)+' and new value is '+newval+'.');
document.getElementById('zoom').style.zoom = Number(oldval) + 0.1;

};
```

And it almost does what I want.

The problem:

It sets the zoom to 0.1 and not to "oldval + 0.1".

So the problem seems to be somewhere around the variable "oldval".

Maybe I cant store the value correctly or I cant use it correctly?

The alert says old value is 0 and new value is 0.1

Comment: To our non-German-speaking friends: *Strg* means *Ctrl*.

Comment: Oh yea. I am sorry. ^^ I edited it. :)

Comment: --> i edited the question and added more information

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can do it like this :

```
document.addEventListener("keypress", zoom, false);

function zoom(e) {
    var keyId = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if (keyId == 17 && keyId == 107 ) {
        window.parent.document.body.style.zoom += 1.5;// choose the factor of zoom

    }
```

Comment: I do not know if this does what I want.
It seems like it zooms when i press + or -. thats not what i wanted. ;)

id like to create a button. if u click that button it zooms in or oout.

Comment: --> i edited the question and added more information

Comment: no it triggers ig Control + "+" is pressed.